# What role will NFT tokens play in the project?

Tags: web3.js, nft

What role will NFT tokens play in the project? I would like to hear the answer to this question, because it will play an important role

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Non-fungible tokens are about as flexible as your imagination allows.  They could represent clothing, weapons, or magic spells in a game, or a sort of pass or membership card that conveys benefits like discounts or airdrops.  Those are common current uses.

Really any situation where you need a unique asset, of limited quantity, to which you can attach arbitrary metadata that you can reference from other parts of your program (or indeed another outside program), might be a good candidate situation to use an NFT.